# Use Flexbox to create a responsive layout

Tags: javascript, css, layout, flexbox

It's the first time I try to use Flexbox and I'm having some problems.

I want to create a responsive layout that works on desktop, tablet and layout like this one:

[image: layout]

I write this code:

```js
var screenType = 'mobile' // this variable return 'mobile' or 'tablet' or 'desktop'
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.big {
  background-color: tomato;
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
}

.small {
  background-color: green;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="big">big</div>
  <div class="small">small</div>
</div>
```

How can I use the variable type to create different layout using Flex?

I think I have to change `width`, `height`, `flex-direction` but I don't know how...

Comment: "How can I use the variable type to create different layout using Flex?" — Don't. Use media queries instead.

Comment: @Quentin Can you explain me how?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have a JS variable that is populated with a preset screen type, then you can use it as a class name that is added to the `<body>` element, e.g.:

```
document.body.classList.add(screenType);
```

And then in your CSS you simply create modifiers of your pre-existing styles, .e.g

```
.container {
  // Default styles for desktop
}

.mobile .container,
.tablet .container {
  // Modified styles for mobile/tablet
}
```

On top of that, you will need to use the `order` property in the flexbox specification, so that you can re-arrange your elements.

A pro-tip: instead of naming your classes by appearance (`big`, `small`, etc.), I strongly suggest giving them a semantic name so that they are decoupled from the appearance. In your example, the `.big` container is big on some devices but is actually small the other devices.

See proof-of-concept example:

```js
function setScreenType() {
  var screenType = document.getElementById('screenType').value;
  document.body.classList.remove('mobile', 'desktop', 'tablet');
  document.body.classList.add(screenType);
}

setScreenType();

document.getElementById('screenType').addEventListener('change', function() {
  setScreenType();
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.content1 {
  background-color: tomato;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  order: 2;
}

.content2 {
  background-color: green;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  order: 1;
}

.mobile .container,
.tablet .container {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.mobile .content1,
.tablet .content1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20%;
  order: 1;
}

.mobile .content2,
.tablet .content2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80%;
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<!-- This is just to simulate different screen types -->
<form>
  <select id="screenType">
    <option value="mobile" selected>Mobile</option>
    <option value="tablet">Tablet</option>
    <option value="desktop">Desktop</option>
  </select>
</form>

<div class="container">
  <div class="content1">content1</div>
  <div class="content2">content2</div>
</div>
```